# Figure not numbered correctly (when combined with subfigures)

Tags: subfloats

I have a problem with the correct numbering of figures when combined with subfigures as the following MWE shows:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\counterwithout{figure}{chapter}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\captionsetup{type=figure}
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.6\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{demo}
    \caption{Sub Heading}
    \end{subfigure}
    \par\bigskip
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.6\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{demo}
    \caption{Sub Heading}
    \end{subfigure}
\captionof{figure}{Main Heading}
\label{fig:Apps_Unterricht_Apple}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Why does it say "Figure 2" instead of "Figure 1"? I know that, in case I use a float environment, the problem is fixed, but I do not want to use such an environment in this case. Any workarounds for this problem?

Comment: Just do `\caption{Main Heading}`. Together with `\captionsetup{type=figure}` you were issuing the `figure` counter twice.

Comment: When removing \captionsetup{type=figure}, I get a couple of error messages saying that the subfigures are not inside a float environment, but I don't want to use such an environment.

Comment: As I said in my first sentence, you only have to change from `\captionof{figure}{Main Heading}` to `\caption{Main Heading}`. Right now you are telling the caption twice that it should be of type figure... that is redundant and in this case false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the solution to this question (for future readers):

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\counterwithout{figure}{chapter}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\captionsetup{type=figure}
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.6\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{demo}
    \caption{Sub Heading}
    \end{subfigure}
    \par\bigskip
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.6\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{demo}
    \caption{Sub Heading}
    \end{subfigure}
\caption{Main Heading}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```